# Comparing two variable in shell

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have two variables 
$a and $b

and

```
$a=Source/dir1/dir11
$b=Destination/dir1/dir11
```

$a and $b changes but initials  Source/ and Destination/ remains same.
**I want to compare $a and $b without Source/ and Destination/**

how should I do it?
Following code I am using

```
   SOURCE_DIR_LIST=`find Source/ -type d`
   DEST_DIR_LIST=`find Destination/ -type d`

for dir_s in $SOURCE_DIR_LIST
do
    for dir_d in $DEST_DIR_LIST
    do

        if [ ${dir_s/Source\//''} == ${dir_d/Destination\//''} ]
        then
                echo " path match = ${dir_s/Source\//''}"

        else
             echo "path does not match source path = ${dir_s/Source\//''} "
             echo " and destination path= ${dir_d/Destination\//''} "
        fi
    done
done
```

But output is coming like as follow

```
 path match = ''
./compare.sh: line 9: [: ==: unary operator expected
path does not match source path = ''
 and destination path= ''dir2
./compare.sh: line 9: [: ==: unary operator expected
more
```

Comment: FYI you're not actually assigning anything in that expression. Lose the dollar signs to do assignments.

Comment: Are the names 'Source' and 'Destination' fixed, or are they paths held in variables?  That could influence the best answer.

Comment: i want to comapre even if it changes like $a=Source/dir1/dir11/mydir. I always want to compare without Source/ and Destination/

Comment: if [ ${a/Source\//''} == ${b/Destination\//''} ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if [ ${a/Source/''} == ${b/Destination/''} ]
then
  # do your job
fi
```

Comment: it is not comparing if $a=Source/dir1/dir11/mydir. I always want to compare without Source/ and Destination/

Comment: change it to if [ ${a/Source\//''} == ${b/Destination\//''} ]

Comment: @Hellboy: this isn't going to work too well for you when you don't understand the shell well enough to recognise a correct answer.  I suggest you find and work through a couple basic scripting tutorials.

Comment: @Tony I really told i don't  know much but I have to do it and I have less time.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ `echo $a | sed 's/Source\///'` == `echo $b | sed 's/Destination\///'` ]
then
    # Do something
fi
```

Comment: Better to use '`$(...)`' than backticks.  Also, bash has a '`<<<`' operator to avoid the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

using `case/esac`

```
case "${a#*/}" in
 ${b#*/} ) echo "ok";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

or with awk

```
 #!/bin/bash
    a="Source/dir1/dir11"
    b="Destination/dir1/dir11"
    SAVEIFS=$IFS
    IFS="\/"
    basea=$(echo $a | awk '{print $1}')
    baseb=$(echo $b | awk '{print $1}') 
    if [ $basea == $baseb ]; then
        echo "Equal strings"
    fi
    IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: You could use '`<<<`' to avoid the `echo | awk` pipeline.  Also, `basea` will contain Source and `baseb` will contain Destination; you need to print all but `$1`.  And it becomes problematic if Source is actually `/mnt/usb-stick/installation/path` and Destination is actually `/opt/SomeBody/Program`.  I am not sure why you have the backslash in the IFS, either.